# unsupported format character 'm'

Tags: python, datetime, string-formatting

I am trying to convert now.month to decimal so it would look like 01 and not like 1. The code is:

```
import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now()
monthstr = ".%m" % now.month
```

it works in this line with %d

```
daystr = "file_%d" % now.day
```

the error I get is

> ValueError: unsupported format character 'm' (0x6d) at index 2

I also tried with the new type {:%m}. The error is the same.
Do i miss any libraries? Or is there another way except adding 0 to months from Jan to September

Python v.3.6.3

Comment: This is string formatting, not datetime formatting, for that you probably want **`strftime`**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using string formatting like datetime formatting here.  String formatting has its own ["mini-language"](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language), and **`m`** is not a valid symbol in this language.

For your purposes, it would be better to use [**`strftime`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime)

```
>>> now.strftime('.%m')
'.07'
```

Comment: Perfect, it works, Thank You! I will accept this as an answer in couple of minutes (stackoverflow limits)

Answer (score 4):

This is because `%d` do not stands for `days`. It stands for digits and is a placeholder for numbers when using string formatting.

You should use it for months also.

```
monthstr = ".%d" % now.month
```

Since you want the format as `01 and not like 1`, use @user3483203 [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51326939/7692463).